# From submartingale to martingale

Tags: probability, expected-value, martingales

Let's consider submartingale, so variable that satisfies :

$$E[X_{n+1}|\mathbb{F}_n] \ge X_n$$

Also let's assume that $\forall_{i, j}:E[X_i]=E[X_j]$

I want to prove that $X_n$ is martingale.

**My work so far**

To prove martingale, we only need to prove that X is supermartingal i.e.
$$E[X_{n+1}|\mathbb{F}_n] \le X_n$$
From very first assumption we have that :

$$E[E[X_{n+1}|\mathbb{F}_n]] \ge E[X_n] \Leftrightarrow X_{n+1} \ge E[X_n]$$

Now from second assumption (equality of expectations) we have that $$X_n \ge E[X_n]$$

And now I stacked. Could you please give me a hand ?

Answer (score 2):

Denote $Z_n:=\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_n]$. You have that $$Z_n-X_n\geq 0.$$ Since $(X_n)$ has constante expectation, $$\mathbb E[Z_n-X_n]=\mathbb E[X_{n+1}]-\mathbb E[X_n]=0,$$
and thus $Z_n=X_n$ a.s. as wished.

Comment: How did you get rid of conditional expected value in second line ? I mean why don't you have $E[Z_n-X_n|\mathbb{F}_n]$ ?